# Internet Explorer 6 css order matters bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer, styles, internet-explorer-6

After maybe all day I explore new bug (for me) in IE6. Order of css styles matters. The style work only for the first child ( in css file, not in element). It's hard to explain, but the examples will show you what I mean.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style>
    #container #p.one
    {
        position: absolute;
        left:50%;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background: green;
    }
    #container #p.two
    {
        position: absolute;
        left:50%;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background: green;
    }
    #container
    {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 500;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="p" class="one">123</div> <!-- change class "one" with "two" -->
    </div>
</body>
```

So, if you change the class "one" with class "two", the div will lose the style.
Style one and two are exactly the same.

But if you change :

```
<div id="p" class="one">
```

with

```
<div id="p" class="two">
```

and change the style from:

```
    #container #p.one
    {
        position: absolute;
        left:50%;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background: green;
    }
    #container #p.two
    {
        position: absolute;
        left:50%;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background: green;
    }
    #container
    {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 500;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

to:

```
    #container #p.two
    {
        position: absolute;
        left:50%;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background: green;
    }
    #container #p.one
    {
        position: absolute;
        left:50%;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background: green;
    }
    #container
    {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 500;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

Just swap class "one" with class "two"
Class "two" will work, but "one" not.
How to fix this or it is impossible?

Comment: Obligatory "stop using IE6 and tell other people to stop using IE6"

Comment: examples of [oxymorons](http://www.answers.com/topic/oxymoron): 1) "Airline food" 2) "Military intelligence" 3) "IE6 CSS" ;)

Comment: Not really constructive advice, guys.

Comment: @Mat neither was that, nor is my hypocrisy ;) IE6 is so terrible that it's almost impossible to stop oneself from bitching about it :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known IE6 bug](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Multiple_Id_Class_Bug). It will ignore every `#id.class` but the first.

Comment: @user1091156 - that's one of the reasons it's a bad idea to support IE6: it has so many bugs, missing features and special cases that it makes it very hard to maintain a site that works in IE6 and also in other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using IDs and classes together in your css rules..  By their very nature, IDs can/should refer to only one element in the page, so #p.two and #p.one should really only be #p???

Comment: I know, but in some weird case this maybe be useful. If have a 2-3 div below <div id="p">, and you want to change the data in this div via ajax, and this data have to be with different style. It's handy to change just the class of the div. However it's possible, just with attach a div with current class in <div id="p">. I'm just wonder do have a fix to this.